# Create a stored procedure called Proc_InsertCustomer that would

Tags: mysql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that would take Firstname and Lastname and optional CustomerID as parameters and Insert into Customer table.

- If CustomerID is not provided, increment the last CustomerID and use that.
- Use the CheckName function to verify that the customer name is correct. 
  How can I create this function inside this procedure */

---

```
 Create Procedure Proc_InsertCustomer 
                @FirstName nvarchar(50), 
                LastName nvarchar(50), 
                @CustomerID int=Null As 
  Begin   
  Insert Into Customer(FirstName, LastName, CustomerID) 
                         Values 
                    (@FirstName
                    , @LastName
                    , @CustomerID)   
   if(@CustomerID=null)
      Set @CustomerID=@@Identity 
  End
```

Comment: As written, even if CustomerID is provided, this will insert a new row anyway. You'll end up with lots of duplicate entries. If the CheckName procedure already exists, call it with the `exec` command.

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of "customer name is correct" in your case.